# SQL: I want to remove duplicate strings

Tags: sql-server, replace, duplicates

How to find and remove duplicates?

Example:

```
Rest of the World. Rest of the World AFC Cup
```

Result:

```
AFC Cup
```

I tried this:

```
DECLARE @STR VARCHAR (20)

SET @STR = 'Rest of the World. Rest of the World. AFC Cup ' 

SELECT LEN (@STR) - LEN (@STR, 'Rest of the World', '')
```

But this is the wrong answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT value 
FROM STRING_SPLIT(@tags, ' ') 
WHERE RTRIM(value) <> ''
GROUP BY value 
HAVING COUNT(VALUE) = 1
```

This should return the individual words in different rows. Use a cursor and iterate over the list and join the words.

Comment: I'd suggest `STRING_AGG` over a `CURSOR`. Iterating will rarely be as quick as a dataset approach in a DBMS.